# How to add State to a Function from Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a layout from Material UI. The function name is called MainMenu. It's in function form, but I want to add states to it. How do I do that? I tried converting it to class, but I don't know how material-ui works....I have deleted some of the code, to cut down on unnecessary bits.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  appBar: {
    position: 'relative',
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
  heroUnit: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  heroUnits: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  heroContent: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    maxWidth: 600,
    margin: '0 auto',
    padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 8}px 0 ${theme.spacing.unit * 6}px`,
  },
  heroButtons: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
  },
  layout: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width: 'auto',
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    [theme.breakpoints.up(1100 + theme.spacing.unit * 3 * 2)]: {
      width: 1100,
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
    },
  },
  cardGrid: {
    padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 8}px 0`,
  },
  card: {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  cardMedia: {
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
  cardContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 6,
  },
});


function MainMenu(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.heroUnits}>
      <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
            Dashboard
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <main>
        <div className={classes.heroUnit}>
          <div className={classes.heroContent}>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h2" align="center" color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
              Synapse
            </Typography>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={classNames(classes.layout, classes.cardGrid)}>
        
        </div>
      </main>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

MainMenu.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MainMenu);
```

Comment: add state = {} to the top of your class and any properties you want inside of it

Comment: It depends on why you're trying to add internal state. Does the state need to be internal to the component or can it be done with props? What kind of state is it?

Comment: im trying to add states for conditional rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted some code for better readability, this is how you do conditional rendering in React.

```
class MainMenu extends React.Component {
    state = { shouldIRender: false}
      const { classes } = this.props;
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
         {this.state.shouldIRender ? <p>sure, render</p> : <p>not rendering</p>}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, i tried this but i get - 'state' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/q9nvr52774

reproduced a small example for you to understand conditional rendering in React.

Comment: its a bit more complicated, because I cant change the function to a class without a lot of errors

Comment: its fine dont worry